# Can more than one Pokémon get Pokérus after encountering a Pokérus-infected wild Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

I was hatching eggs with a Talonflame at the front of my party, when I accidentally ran into the grass. Afterwards, I accidentally ran into the grass again and once again ran like last time.

Then, when the egg in my second slot (top right) hatched, I noticed that it had Pokérus. I just put it in my box and kept hatching eggs. But when I hatched the next egg (formerly in the third slot of my party, now in second) I noticed it also had Pokérus. After checking the Wikipedia article on Pokérus, it said that it could only spread adjacently, so after that second battle it could've only spread to either my Talonflame or my egg in the fourth slot and not the egg in the third slot.

So my question is: **Can Pokérus spread to two Pokémon at once after encountering an infected wild Pokémon, or did I find two Pokérus-infected Pokémon in a row?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Adjacent" in the context of a player's party means one index value less or greater.  Visually, this may seem like the virus spreads diagonally sometimes because the party in this and several other generations are arranged in a 2x3 grid.

However, if you look at the organization of the party in Gen VIII for example, the second Pokémon is obviously adjacent to the first and third Pokémon.  This same logic is applied to Gens 3-7 even if the party screen is arranged differently.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I was really confused because the chances of two pokerus encounters in a row is extremely small (1/470,000,000 or so)